# how can I use an xpath selector to get the price from this table cell?

Tags: xpath, domdocument

given

```
<TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="top" WIDTH="35">&nbsp;</TD><TD ALIGN="LEFT" VALIGN="top" WIDTH="150" STYLE="font-size: 11px; font-family: arial" HEIGHT="65"> <a href="http://www.site.com/page/IDLM/DATA/VALUE/10001600"><B><i>Brand</i></B><BR>Part</a><BR>
$72.00
 </TD>
```

is there an xpath selector that will retrieve only the price? I can use

```
//td/text()
```

to retrieve

```
Array
(
    [0] => Â 
    [1] => 

    [2] => Â 
    [3] => Â 
    [4] =>  
    [5] => 
$72.00

    [6] => Â 
)
```

and then use a regex to throw out the bad values, but I think it will be more reliable to use a proper xpath selector.

Comment: i think <BR> is not formatted properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. Deciding which is best depends on your actual, real-life source input. Based on the sample you've provided, I would pivot on the final `BR` element:

```
//TD/BR[last()]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

This expression selects the first text node that follows the last `BR` element in any `TD` in the document. Note that this node contains leading and trailing spaces. Wrap the expression with the `normalize-space` function to remove them.

Comment: thanks that works. I am confused how to apply normalize-space() as what I have read suggests that `//td/br[last()]/following-sibling::text()[1][normalize-space()]` would apply normalize-space() to the current node but this doesn't work